# Wordpress website shows 404 page for folder + images if directly accessed?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Hello guys what can be the reason for this:

I have a folder "wallpapers" not related to my website (Wordpress) in the same web hosting and images inside. If i wanted to access them I would go to website.com/wallpapers/myimage.jpg and it worked!

But I noticed it doesn't work anymore now I see my wordpress site + error 404 inside the website.

I have tried to fix this disabled few plugins etc... but where should I look? What can be the reason? Maybe the htaccess?

Thanks!

Comment: try resaving your `settings` -> `permalinks` it will reset the WP rewrite rules in `.htaccess`. Because default WP should allow it.

Comment: Oops - sorry @janw, answered and then noticed you'd pretty much said the same thing :)

Comment: @janw Mcnab thanks! You guys helped me with another mystery why sometimes my htaccess replaces itself! This happens when you save permalinks! Well I did that but still error 404 :( Does it help maybe? I have .htaccess in the folder wallpaper aswell for that folder can it be a conflict?

Comment: @McNab you really answered the question I just point and say look there ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I think your guess on the .htaccess is perfectly correct.  If you enable permalinks in Wordpress it automatically creates, or tries to create (depending on permissions) the following .htaccess file;

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

The two lines in this that are relevant to you are;

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

What they are basically doing is making sure that every url request gets run through the index.php in the root *except* any files or directories that actually exist as separate files and directories outwith the Wordpress install (ie your wallpapers directory). So first of all I would make sure that your .htaccess looks like this.

Comment: My htaccess looks like this now I have edited it but still 404 error. I'm using CloudFlare if it makes any difference?

Comment: oh should I add that folder wallpaper has .htaccess file aswell maybe there is conflict with that? Hmmm weird it worked before...

Comment: What does the subdirectory .htaccess contain?  Looking around I've seen the solution that you would turn off the rewrite engine on your subdirectory.htaccess - "RewriteEngine Off"

Comment: I acctullay have RewriteEngine On over there with my rules:) seems like it's the issue that .htaccess doesn't work looking for a way to solve it too :)

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do the same in the past, and it drove me nuts so if that can help here's what I've done. I had the default .htaccess wordpress created in my wordpress folder when activating the permalinks option, the folloowing :

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

for some reason...

I could access http://example.com/phpinfo.php fine, 
but http://example.com/myfolder was returning a 404, despite (if I'm correct) the line RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d should allow me to show what was into that folder as it's existing and having the correct permissions (user:user chmoded 755)

after having tried everything I could find on the subject, I ended up creating a **.htaccess** into my folder "**/myfolder**"

with the unique following line in it :

```
Options +Indexes
```

And I finally got http://example.com/myfolder to answer the response 200 OK

I suppose this is not the best ever solution but it's the only one that worked for me and as I just need this to work for one or two folders, it did not need to be more adaptive / flexible